# SQL: find the longest path

Tags: sql, postgresql, graph

I'm totally new to graph theory, and having a hard time wrapping my head around this problem. Given a simple table below (unidirected), how can I find the longest path from a defined start and end point using a select statement?

It would seem that some recursive statement is required, but I had trouble understanding it. If anyone can help with an example it will be great.

I am using Postgresql.

```
+ -------- + ------ + -------- +
| fromnode | tonode | distance |
+ -------- + ------ + -------- +
| 1        | 2      | 1306     |
| 1        | 6      | 2661     |
| 2        | 3      | 919      |
| 2        | 4      | 629      |
| 3        | 4      | 435      |
| 3        | 5      | 1225     |
| 3        | 7      | 1983     |
| 5        | 6      | 1483     |
| 5        | 7      | 1258     |
+ -------- + ------ + -------- +
```

Comment: Although you *can* do this in Postgres using recursive CTEs, I'm not sure it is the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can to this recursive CTEs, like:

```
with recursive params as (
  select 1 fromnode,
         7 tonode
),
paths as (
    select ARRAY[fromnode] pathnodes,
           fromnode lastnode,
           0 sumdistance
    from   params
  union all
    select     pathnodes || e.tonode,
               e.tonode,
               sumdistance + e.distance
    from       paths
    join       edges e on e.fromnode = lastnode
    cross join params p
    where      e.fromnode <> p.tonode
    and        e.tonode <> all(pathnodes)
)
select   pathnodes, sumdistance
from     paths, params
where    lastnode = tonode
order by sumdistance desc
limit    1
```

(Casts *may* be required here and there, depending on the types of your columns.)

http://rextester.com/VRFHK43986

However, this will always calculate every possible paths (which starts at `params.fromnode`; without circles) & will choose the longest of them, after that.

**Edit**: the solution above assumes that the graph is directed. If it's undirected, you can modify it, to make use of edges from `tonode` to `fromnode` too:

```
with recursive params as (
  select 7 fromnode,
         1 tonode
),
paths as (
    select ARRAY[fromnode] pathnodes,
           fromnode lastnode,
           0 sumdistance
    from   params
  union all
    select     pathnodes || e.nodeb,
               e.nodeb,
               sumdistance + e.distance
    from       paths
    cross join lateral (select fromnode nodea,
                               tonode   nodeb,
                               distance
                        from   edges
                        where  fromnode = lastnode
                        union
                        select tonode   nodea,
                               fromnode nodeb,
                               distance
                        from   edges
                        where  tonode = lastnode) e
    cross join params p
    where      e.nodea <> p.tonode
    and        e.nodeb <> all(pathnodes)
)
select   pathnodes, sumdistance
from     paths, params
where    lastnode = tonode
order by sumdistance desc
limit    1;
```

However, a unique index may be required on `(LEAST(fromnode, tonode), GREATEST(fromnode, tonode))` to avoid duplication, where `row1.fromnode = row2.tonode and row1.tonode = row2.fromnode`. (The query does not handle such kind of duplication & will calculate with 2 separate paths in this case).

http://rextester.com/XEGAX60117

Comment: thanks @pozs. Looks like it works exactly as I hope it could. Is this what they call as Dijkstra's Algorithm?

Comment: hi @pozs, noticed that this is a directed graph, I can make it as a bidirected one by modifying the main table as (select * from edges union select tonode as fromnode, fromnode as tonode, distance from edges). but do u think this is an efficient way?

Comment: @Jake this is hardly an algorithm, and work a little different from Dijkstra's. -- Yes, the original solution assumes that it is a directed graph. You could do that, but you can also modify the query to work with undirected graphs too. I'll update my answer soon.

Comment: @Jake I see now, what could be the source of confusion: *unidirected* means directed (in a single direction). But it also may be a typo of *undirected* (which is not directed, OFC). -- [Bidirected graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirected_graph) are may not be, what you think they are.

Comment: oh ya, pardon my language. Appreciate ur explanation :)